# Combining style attributes this way

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 >This is a heading</h1>
<p style="color:blue" "font-size:300%">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to combine two **style** attributes this way? How does one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have to add a single `style` attribute with properties separated by `;`, for sample:

```
<p style="color:blue; font-size:300%">This is a paragraph.</p>
```